# Android NDK and dropping in new shared libraries

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared

I have a question regarding why I cannot simply drop in new shared libraries in Android without recompiling via NDK-build. Heres what i do:

Using Android Studio and the recent release of the Android NDK, I have been able to compile an app that uses a C code, which refers to a shared library. I compile the shared library with:

```
GCC := /xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc.exe
GPP :=/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-g++.exe
AR  := /xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-ar.exe

OPTIONS  :=\
 -ffunction-sections \
 -funwind-tables  \
 -DANDROID 

default: all
all: obj
    $(AR) r libmathadd.so mathadd.o

obj:
    $(GCC) $(OPTIONS) -c mathadd.c
```

This gives me my .so file. I now run my ndk-build with the Android.mk makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE           := mathadd
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        :=./libmathadd.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := mathadd
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Following this, I have my ndk1 .so file and my mathadd .so which i then place in a folder directory:

app -> src -> jniLibs -> x86 -> libmathadd.so

and

app -> src -> jniLibs -> x86 -> libndk1.so

I compile and run on my emulator, and boom everything works!

**Now heres my problem.**
I slightly modify my shared library source (mathadd.c). I recompile it using the first make file and drop it straight into the app tree (without rebuilding the native c code) . I rebuild the app in Studio, and run on my emulator, and notice that my modifications did not occur.

I am not changing my native source, nor the api between native and my shared library.

If I rebuild the native with the ndk-build script, and drag the new native ndk1 in, everything works again, including the new modifcations. It seems I need to rebuild source via ndk everytime I tweak a shared library...??

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: 
I opened up my libndk .so library with a RE tool. Turns out the ndk compiler is statically adding the libmathadd code into the libndk, despite it being listed as a local shared library. Im curious if this is because the optimization is by default set for fastest speed, and the libmathadd code is simplistic math.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So libndk1.so has a dependency on libmath.so ? That would then be logical to rebuild it when you touch to libmath source.

Comment: yes, libndk1.so has a dependency on libmathadd.so. Specifically it uses helper functions from libmathadd. However I have always been under the impression that , so long as the function header does not change, the original would not need to be rebuilt when the shared library is modified, as the helper function code is not statically compiled into libndk1.